# ADB unable to connect my Nexus 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: adb, nexus-7, linux

I want to be able to connect my Nexus 7 in order to test my applications from Eclipse on the physical device.

I followed [this Google guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file contains this :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e42", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e40", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4e41", MODE="0666"
```

The device is configured to use `"Camera (PTP)"` and `"USB debugging"` is checked too.

But `adb devices` lists no device.

What have I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the "Connected" message only appeared sometimes and that `lsusb` was unable to detect the Nexus casted a doubt on the cable.

I just tested with another cable and it works. My other cable seems to have a damaged connector.

Comment: As I saw many times since that ADB connectors are fragile and very susceptible to this kind of problem, I keep this answer which might help other people. There's obviously a flaw in the design of those connectors.